# Downloading packages in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the "forecast" package for R on my production server (CentOS 7)using the install.packages("forecast") command. However, the packages requires the "tseries" package as a dependency which requires the "quantmod" and "curl" packages.

When i finally tried to download the "curl" package using install.packages("curl") it said -

ERROR: configuration failed for package 'curl'

How do I get the forecast package up and running with R?

Comment: Try `install.packages("forecast", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: Try to `install.packages("curl", type = "source")`. Then check if there are any more details about the error.

Comment: Look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) under `SystemRequirements` and make sure you have these on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to install those other packages manually — they will be installed automatically when you install {forecast}. However, in order to install the {curl} package, your *system* first needs to have libcurl installed. This happens outside R, and is therefore not done automatically.

You need to consult your operating system’s instructions for how to install such packages. Often there’s a package manager which allows you to install software easily.

For instance, on many Linux systems you can use

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

On macOS, the easiest way is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install curl
```

On Windows, the process is unfortunately substantially more difficult.

[The README file of the {curl} package has more detailed instructions.](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#installation)